# Does RecognitionListener.onError() automatically SpeechRecognizer.cancel()?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

For various reasons, I need to use the raw `SpeechRecognizer` API instead of the easier `RecognizerIntent` (RECOGNIZE_SPEECH) [activity](http://hi-android.info/src/android/speech/RecognitionService.java.html).

That means, among other things, that I need to handle `RecognitionListener.onError()` myself.

In response to some of the errors, I simply want to re-start listening. This looks straightforward but when I just call `SpeechRecognizer.startListening()` upon error, this  sometimes seems to trigger two different errors:

```
 ERROR/ServerConnectorImpl(619): Previous session not destroyed
```

and

```
"concurrent startListening received - ignoring this call"
```

Which hints that I should have done some cleanup before attempting to call `SpeechRecognizer.startListening()` again.

If this is true, it means that upon a RecognitionListener error, listening is not automatically stopped and/or canceled.

It is also possible that some errors do stop/cancel listening, while others don't. There are really only 9 [SpeechRecognizer](http://hi-android.info/src/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java.html) errors:

1. ERROR_NETWORK_TIMEOUT
2. ERROR_NETWORK
3. ERROR_AUDIO
4. ERROR_SERVER
5. ERROR_CLIENT
6. ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT
7. ERROR_NO_MATCH
8. ERROR_RECOGNIZER_BUSY
9. ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS

Since the documentation isn't very detailed about which error cancels listening and which doesn't, do you happen to know, based on your experience, which errors require doing cleanup (and to which extent) *before* attempting `SpeechRecognizer.startListening()` again?

Comment: Not many people would know enough to reply here. I'd suggest you try catching the errors and Log.w them accordingly instead of waiting for an answer. You should be able to find out which errors close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `cancel` is not called when `onError` is invoked. You can look at the source [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java).

Comment: the source link is not available.

Comment: Indeed: who would have thought the original link would move after almost a decade. Updated.

Comment: @Femi True. `cancel()` is **not** called when `onError()` is invoked. But one could argue that this is not needed because listening has already been effectively canceled by virtue of the error condition. At least [according the source code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75074233/2597758). Do you agree?

Answer (score 1):

you can destroy current session by destroy(). And you can restart it again

Answer (score 1):

Actually Femi, some of the error conditions DO stop the transcription service from listening (SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT for example).  It is not necessary to call destroy, just startlistening again.

Comment: Actually @Shroud, if you look at the [source code](http://hi-android.info/src/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.java.html) I posted in my original question, you'll see that `SpeechRecognizer.ERROR_SPEECH_TIMEOUT` isn't handled any differently than other errors. All errors are relayed by `mInternalHandler.handleMessage()` to  `mInternalListener.onError()`. Which in turn relays it to `Message.obtain(mInternalHandler, MSG_ERROR, error).sendToTarget();`. Where do you see it sopping the transcription service?