# Is there a way to tell when SpeechRecognizer.cancel() processing has completed successfully?

Tags: android, android-speech-api

Once [SpeechRecognizer.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#cancel()) is invoked, is there a way to tell that it has been completely processed, to the point of not interpreting any sound an microphone and not invoking any of its [ReognitionListener callbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener)?

More specifically, when [SpeechRecognizer.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#cancel()) is invoked, all it does is place a MSG_CANCEL in the main thread's queue:

```
@MainThread
public void cancel() {
    checkIsCalledFromMainThread();
    putMessage(Message.obtain(mHandler, MSG_CANCEL));
}
```

Then, at some point (no immediacy guarantee), the message is handled:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_START:
                handleStartListening((Intent) msg.obj);
                break;
            case MSG_STOP:
                handleStopMessage();
                break;
            case MSG_CANCEL:
                handleCancelMessage();
                break;
```

by further relaying it to the `IRecognitionService` service:

```
private void handleCancelMessage() {
    if (!checkOpenConnection()) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        mService.cancel(mListener, /*isShutdown*/ false);
        if (DBG) Log.d(TAG, "service cancel command succeeded");
    } catch (final RemoteException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "cancel() failed", e);
        mListener.onError(ERROR_CLIENT);
    }
}
```

But I have not been able to find any callback or listener that notifies the app when the `IRecognitionService` has completed **successfully**.

Any idea for a way to tell when [SpeechRecognizer.cancel()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer#cancel()) processing has completed **successfully**?